# format damaged HD

Tags: mount, external-hdd, format

I have an WD MyPassport external HD that won't even mount anymore. I have tried several things (most of which suggestions from this forum), such as using `testdisk`, `mkfs.ext4`, `mkfs.ext3`, `mkfs.ntfs` and etc. At this point, as you can see, I don't really care about the files anymore. I would just like to be able to use my HD again. Any help is appreciated.

PS.: some outputs you might find useful

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/wd/
mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock

$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdb | grep superblock
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
dumpe2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

The command `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` outputs nothing.
The "zero partition" part cought my eye, but I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to completely wipe the first GByte of the disk:

**Warning: *The command dd is the abbreviation of Disk Destroyer! Use with care!!!***

```
sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/XdY bs=512 count=1G
```

where X and Y are the correct parameters for the disk (Probably `s` and `b`) If I were you, I would remove all hard disks from this computer, except the faulty one, boot from a LiveCD and then execute the command!

P.S. Some people don't understand that re-using an old disk can be a life saver.  Read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) and then look at the number of upvotes per answer!  ;-)

Comment: This worked! I don't get how, though. I followed your command exactly (with `count=1G`) and it ran almost instantly. Naturally I thought it hadn't worked but then I checked the HDD and it was mounted! I could even access the data. Can you please explain what happened?

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...

Comment: I'm as surprised as you!  It should have destroyed the first GB of data on your disk.  Can you [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), refer to this one and post a screen shot of `gparted` of that disk? and then leave a comment with the new question below here?

Comment: Don't worry, I was already going to mark your answer ;) I was just curious as to how it worked. I didn't think it was worth a new question though. I wouldn't even know how to precisely formulate it without telling the whole story!

Comment: Post a link to the screenshot then here in the comments and give me an upvote!  ;-)

Comment: That is a good idea, except that I already formatted it as an ext3 partition, fearing that I wouldn't have the same luck when I connected the device again!

Comment: We'll never know now!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If it won't mount more then likely you have a bad sector (which is why you can't access your files), It's cheaper just to replace the hard drive then to spend time fixing it if that is the case, I would unscrew the case and just buy a 3.5inch drive and replace it. It's pretty simple to do that.

Comment: I see you're assuming that I live in a developed country, where these things are cheap. This is not the case (unfortunately). So I would reeeally like to avoid throwing out this hard drive if possible.

Comment: How much is your time worth? Find an hourly rate multiply it by the amount of time you've spent on this issue then find out if it's cheaper then replacing the hard drive. I know my time is worth about $25.00 an hour so I know working on a hard drive for more then 4 hours doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but you're leaving out the learning part.

Comment: But if your paritition is messed up then your hard drive is dead. You can't revive something that is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Try mounting the first partition /dev/sdb1 instead of the device /dev/sdb
Likewise for the other commands, use the partition.
Now while it is possible to have created the disk without partitions, that's not likely, but if you did, then include the loop option in the mount command -- ie. treat it like a big file.

---

The partitionless disk you created should be mounted with a loop option, something like:

```
sudo mount -text4 -oloop,rw  /dev/sdb /mnt/somewhere
```

Haven't done that but once, so might have left something out. The above assumes an ext4 type filesystem, use the type you used when you created the filesystem on the disk.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but there are no partitions in this disk. It's one whole thing. I didn't get the include loop part in case it doesn't have partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I didn't really understand your command, though. The `-text4` is not accepted by `mount` (neither `-t ext4`). The only way I could make the command work was with `sudo mount -o loop -w /dev/sdb /media/wd/`, and the answer was the same: `mount: /dev/loop0: can't read superblock`.